# How do you import a list of classes from a module?

Tags: python, class, import, module, python-import

Is there a way to import only a specific, predefined list of classes from a Python module? For example, say that I had modules `a.py` and `b.py` in the same directory with the following code:

```
#a.py
class Foo(object):
    '''definition of class Foo goes here'''

class Bar(object):
    '''definition of class Bar goes here'''

aTypes = [Foo, Bar]
```

_

```
#b.py
from a import aTypes

print Foo
```

Running `b.py` causes, of course, the `print Foo` line to raise a `NameError`. I didn't really think that this would work (the import statement in `b.py` gives me an `a.Foo` type instead of a `Foo` type), but I can't figure out the right syntax. Is there an alternative to `from a import aTypes` that gives the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you really do need to do this (deal with list of types) and can't use tricks like `__all__` that only work once (one such special list per module), then:

```
def gettypes(types):
    thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
    for t in types:
        setattr(thismodule, t.__name__, t)
```

Use it like this:

```
import a
gettypes(a.aTypes)
```

I'm finding it difficult to imagine why you'd need this, but that's not my problem ;-)

Note the use of `__name__` means this doesn't work for symbols in general, only for classes, modules, functions and anything else I've forgotten (or at a pinch for objects of your own design that have a `__name__`). It also won't work for things you've aliased in the module, for example by writing `Baz = Bar` in the module and then using `Baz` in the list. If the list was `['Foo', 'Bar']` instead of `[Foo, Bar]`, and you also passed the source module into `gettypes`, then you could avoid those restrictions.

Comment: The first argument of `gettypes` isn't necessary?

Answer (score 4):

You could import the names directly:

```
from a import Foo, Bar
```

Alternately, you could define [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) in `a.py`:

```
__all__ = ['Foo', 'Bar']
```

and then do a wildcard import in `b.py`:

```
from a import *
```

For just two names though, it would be easier to use the first solution.

Comment: Not only easier, but probably the best. This way, anyone can know where the symbol come from just by looking at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `__all__` at the module level of `a.py`:

```
__all__ = ['Foo', 'Bar']
```

This will allow you to import it in the following way:

```
from a import *
```

Of course, this behaviour isn't always encouraged, and the alternative is preferred:

```
from a import Foo, Bar
```